# Centering to the screen

Tags: css

I want put `sign in` button to center both horizontal and vertical of the page in [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/paAqa/). I have tried put anchor tag into another div but it hasn't worked. How can i do that?

Comment: You don't mention if you want to centre horizontally and/or vertically... Any way, there are tonnes of posts about it, please search or specify better the question.

Comment: It's probably one of the most [asked questions in the CSS tag](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18746827/1846192). How about a [search on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=center+element+) first?

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

Comment: @MathijsFlietstra I have a additional problem which most of the questions don't include. There is a transparent cover. So i can't use z-index and i have to use `position: `

Comment: @Tahtakafa - That doesn't make much sense, `z-index` has nothing to do with centering and using `position:` is also a given when positioning things. To me it looks like you don't want to put any effort into having a look at how to do it yourself. If you have a look at the first link in my previous question, it explains clearly how to center any element, and it looks like you're quite capable of adding a transparent cover to it.

Answer (score 2):

Centering things is the hardest problem in the computer sciences.

Well actually it depends whether you want vertical or horizontal centering. Horizontal centering can be achieved by either setting text-align: center on the parent, or by giving the element an explicit width, and margin: auto;

Vertical centering is more difficult. You can set the margin-top: or absolutely position the top: of the element to push it down, but you have to position it at (50% of container height) - (element height / 2), which CSS can't do automatically. If the element or it's container change heights you'll need to adjust manually or with Javascript.

It's still a relatively new technique but the flexible box-model is great at doing this. It's a little more complicated, and there are a lot of vendor prefixes and browser inconsisencies to work around, but you can google it.

Everybody's gonna hate me for saying this, but back in my day we'd have just used a table and gone on with our lives. See table cells allow you to use vertical-align: middle; to do exactly what you'd expect it to do.

```
#abusedTable{
    width: 100%;
}
#abusedTable td{
    height: 500px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/arkanciscan/5WYmx/

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the absolute positioning on your button, and put "text-align: center" on a div that contains the button.

Answer (score 0):

change the code into this

html:

```
<div id="signupCover"><a id="signin_button" href="./index.php">Sign in</a></div>
```

css:

```
#signupCover {

    background-color: #ccc;
    opacity:0.6;
    z-index: 1;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

#signin_button{
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #0096cc;
    padding: 14px 24px 14px 24px;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight:700;
    color: #cca;
    z-index: 99;
}
#signin_button:hover{
    background-color: #0277a3;
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
#signin_button{
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #0096cc;
    padding: 14px 24px 14px 24px;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight:700;
    color: #cca;
    z-index: 99;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:100px;
}
#signin_button:hover{
    background-color: #0277a3;
    color: white;
}
</style>
<a id="signin_button" href="./index.php">Sign in</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have your code like http://jsfiddle.net/judearasu/YvbZX/

```
<div>
<a href="javascript:void(0);">Sign In</a>
</div>

*{
  padding: 0px;
  margin:0px;
 }
div
 {
  background-color: #0096cc;
  padding: 14px 24px 14px 24px;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight:700;
  color: #cca;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```